How to use a custom authorization server for MS Office with OAuth2?
I am implementing a WebDav server and struggle with adding proper OAuth2 support to allow MS office applications to access files directly.
I followed this answer to get the workflow started. Let's say my resource server is https://my.resource and my authorization endpoint is https://my.auth. When I open any file from my resource server (e.g., https://my.resource/myfile) from Word or Excel, the office application issues a couple of OPTIONS, HEAD, and PROPFIND requests to the resource server with the following headers (among others):
Authorization: Bearer
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word     (and a couple others)

The resource server responds with a 401 Unauthorized and includes the following header:
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri="https://my.auth"

My assumption was that Word will access the authorization endpoint and present the form to the user. However, it does not do that. Instead, it displays a standard Microsoft login page and never requests the authorization endpoint.
How can I make the office applications use my custom authorization endpoint?

Unfortunately Word doesn't support true bearer auth, its a custom authentication protocol called X-MSOAUTH - what is your IDP? If you are using AzureAD you can "fake it"...

@JanMartin It's a custom IDP included in my website. I have full control over the IDP and can implement whatever is necessary. I just don't know what protocol to implement (I have tried a few already).

Unfortunately it has to be AzureAD, Microsoft has hardcoded their authentication to flow to talk to login.microsoftonline.com, it was only ever intended to work for SharePoint Online but if you use AzureAD (or Entra as they now call it) you can mimic a SP auth flow
